# CS-Cart Description not showing on featured products

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

In my grid_list.tpl I have the smarty code:

```
{if $product.short_description}
  {$product.short_description nofilter}
{else}
  {$product.full_description|strip_tags|truncate:150:"..."}
{/if}
```

This seems to work fine for the category pages, but not for the 'Featured' or 'Similar' products which use the same template.

Does anyone know how to fix this?